# Error: variable ‘database’ has initializer but incomplete type?

Tags: c, struct

I have this typedef struct and a "constructor":

```
typedef struct database {
    char key;
    char value;
    struct database *next;
} Database;


Database db_createDb() {
    Database *db;
    db = malloc(sizeof(struct database));

    return *db;
}
```

And I am making a call from the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Database database = db_createDb();
}
```

Why am I getting the error "database’ has initializer but incomplete type"?

Comment: That is a 100% memory leak. Why you do this? (`Database database;` is enough for this case)

Comment: @KirilKirov Because OP is here to Learn.

Comment: Why, where? The purpose is to initalize an empty database (I will also have functions to insert and update the database later).

Comment: Also: I would like the structure (the list) to be invincible from the main function, as the database handlers exists in a separate module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `database`by `Database`, and keep pointer for later free:

```
Database * db_createDb() 
{
    Database *db;
    db = (Database *)malloc(sizeof(Database));

    return db;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Database * database = db_createDb();

    ....
    free(database);

}
```

Comment: Does it matter (for transparent module purpose) if I do malloc in the "constructor" or in the main function? I think that the code would be more clear if I also had a deconstructor that call free, if I have a constructor who calls malloc.

Comment: Really doesn't matter. I agree, a good practice is, if you have a 'constructor', develop a 'destructor'

Comment: When I add 'database->key = "Something";' to the main function, I get the error "Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type". Why is that?

Comment: Ok, I think you must review your C knowledge: you defined key as char, not as char *. You may find a lot of resources in Internet